# "Opportunity Record Type" standard field not showing correct value

Tags: opportunity, record-type, standard-field

Having a hard time explaining the problem because i don't understand it.

[image: Opportunity Record Type in record view]

[image: Same record and field values extracted with query]

The standard field "Opportunity Record Type" does not show the correct value,
the two pictures are of the same record, as you can see it should show "Accord Cadre" in thefield but instead it shows "PSL/Master Agreement" which  is a **Deleted** record type, this also happens while using filters in reports on opportunityrecordtype field, the picklist values still contain that of the deleted record type, and not the other one.

I'm lost on this, and am happy to provide more information but don't know what is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_recordtype_considerations.htm&type=5),

> Deactivating a record type means that no new records can be created
> with the record type. However, any records that were previously
> created with the record type are still associated with it and with its
> associated page layout.

As per this, the record type is not deleted it is just deactivated.

Comment: Thank you for that, but i want to confirm to you that the record type " PSL/Master Agreement " is indeed deleted! when i query " select id, name from RecordType " it does not show up. and that record was not previously created, i just created before posting that question for testing